# urllib2.urlopen addinfourl instance has not attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, json

I'm running this python 3 script:

```
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker')[2])
```

and I get this error when it runs:

```
Attribute error: addinfourl instance has no attribute'__getitem__'

 19 while True:
 20   lcd.clear()
 21   url = 'http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker'
 22   data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))['return']
 23   lcd.message(datetime.now().strftime('%b %d %H:%M:%S\n'))
 24   lcd.message( "MtGox: " + data["return"]["last"]["display"])
 25   sleep(10)
```

Comment: First, this can't possibly be a Python 3 script, because Python 3 has no `urllib2`. So… is this not your actual code, or is it Python 2?

Comment: Second, what did you expect this to do? `urlopen` returns a fancy file-like object. Files aren't indexable like lists, and neither are `urlopen` file-like objects.

Comment: It's not my code, but I tried running in python 2.7 and i still get the same error... what would you suggest using instead?

Comment: It _can't_ give you the same error. Python 2.7 will give you this `AttributeError`. Python 3.x will give you an `ImportError` or `NameError` before you can even get here. It really is important to know which one you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
url = 'http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker'
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))['return']
```

urllib2.urlopen doesn't return a list, so you can't index on it. Also, the data you're getting back is a dict, so you need to use valid keys to access the data.  An index won't work.

Comment: I'm getting a "Key error" on 'return' now: lcd.message( "MtGox: " + data["return"]["last"]["display"])

Comment: Great! You may want to update your code to reflect the final solution.